# Why declare properties on the prototype for instance variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

I'm trying to get my head around this black art called JavaScript - and, I must admit, pretty excited about it. I've been looking at code examples, mainly from "easeljs" since that is what I will be using mainly. And I'm a bit confused..

I (think I) understand the difference between using the `prototype` for functions or properties that are `class` variables and using `this.someProp` for 'instance' variables (Yes, I understand that there are no classes in JavaScript.)

The code I have looked at, and am using as templates for my own code, `declare` `prototype` variables and then refers to them with this i.e.

In the constructor:

```
this.name = name;
```

Then a declaration:

```
Object.prototype.name;
```

And later,

```
this.name = "Freddy";
```

This is within functions called with 'new' so in this case, as I understand it, `this` refers to the current object. What puzzles me is what the prototype declaration is doing and why do we use it for instance variables?

---

**Clarification**: In the following code, I don't see what the prototype declaration of radius is achieving:

```
(function(){
    // constructor
    function MyCircle(radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    MyCircle.prototype.radius;
    this.area = function(){
        return 3.14*this.radius*this.radius;
    };
    window.MyCircle = MyCircle;
}());
```

Comment: @jayeshjain not the same question - this one is about declaring "normal values" on the prototype, not functions.

Comment: re: your edit - the code in question makes so sense.  The line that just says `MyCircle.prototype.radius` does nothing.

Comment: The line `MyCircle.prototype.radius;` is not a declaration. It's an anonymous access to an `undefined` property. It's essentially the same as writing `undefined;`.

Comment: The line `MyCircle.prototype.radius` appears to be free of any side-effects and could be removed without altering the behaviour of the code. It might merely be there as an effort to document the property.

Comment: The response from the folks at easeljs is: 
Prototyping is the proper way to put properties on objects that will be instantiated.
Any comments on this?

Comment: @DaveM adding values on the prototype is a good way to add _default_ properties on objects that will be instantiated.  It would be interesting to see your question and their response in full.

Answer (score 59):

The value on a prototype has a key behaviour that is different from a property set directly on the instance. Try this:

```
// Create a constructor
function A() {}

// Add a prototype property
A.prototype.name = "Freddy";

// Create two object instances from
// the constructor
var a = new A();
var b = new A();

// Both instances have the property
// that we created on the prototype
console.log(a.name); // Freddy
console.log(b.name); // Freddy

// Now change the property on the
// prototype
A.prototype.name = "George";

// Both instances inherit the change.
// Really they are just reading the
// same property from the prototype
// rather than their own property
console.log(a.name); // George
console.log(b.name); // George
```

This would not possible without prototypical inheritance.

You can test whether the property is the instances property or the prototype property using the `hasOwnProperty` method.

```
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty("name")); // false
```

An instance can override the `prototype` value.

```
b.name = "Chris";
console.log(b.hasOwnProperty("name")); // true
console.log(a.name); // George
console.log(b.name); // Chris
```

And return to the `prototype` value.

```
delete b.name;
console.log(b.hasOwnProperty("name")); // false
console.log(b.name); // George
```

This is a powerful part of prototypical inheritance.

In the other pattern:

```
function A() {
  this.name = "George";
}
```

The `this.name` variable is declared again with every new instance.

It makes some sense to have methods as functions declared on the prototype. Rather than the function definition being re-declared on every instance, all instances can share a single function.

In terms of variables, rather than functions, the prototype can possibly be used for default values in the case that an instance does not set its own value.

[The code in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EvGsx/)

Comment: Yes, I get that. But the code I've been looking at is more like this:

Answer (score 11):

A value stored on the prototype provides a *default* value for that property.

If you subsequently write a value to that property, the *instance* will acquire that new value, hiding the value that's on the prototype, which will be left intact.

In the context of the code you've now added to the question:

```
MyCircle.prototype.radius;
```

does absolutely nothing.  It's a no-op - it attempts to *read* that property and then discards the result.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I agree the prototype can be used for default values of properties (variables).  The constructor function doesn't need to declare a property; it may be done conditionally.

```
function Person( name, age ) {
    this.name = name;

    if ( age ) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log( 'My name is ' + this.name + '.' );
};

Person.prototype.sayAge = function() {
    if ( this.age ) {
        console.log( 'I am ' + this.age + ' yrs old!' ); 
    } else {
        console.log( 'I do not know my age!' );
    }
};

Person.prototype.age = 0.7;

//-----------

var person = new Person( 'Lucy' );
console.log( 'person.name', person.name ); // Lucy
console.log( 'person.age', person.age );   // 0.7
person.sayAge();                           // I am 0.7 yrs old!
```

See how Lucy's `age` is conditionally declared and initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have already explained the difference between prototype vs instance properties.

But just to add to the answer, let's break down your code snippet:

```
(function(){                         // <------- 1
   // constructor
   function MyCircle(radius){        // <------- 2
       this.radius = radius;         // <------- 2.1
   }
   MyCircle.prototype.radius;        // <------- 3
   this.area = function(){           // <------- 4
       return 3.14*this.radius*this.radius;
   };
   window.MyCircle = MyCircle;       // <------- 5
}());
```

1. Creating an `IIFE` which acts as a scope container for the inner code
2. Declaring a function called `MyCircle` using a constructor pattern *(but observe that it never gets "constructed" so should probably get rid of the capital letter since it's misleading)*

   - when invoked creates a `radius` instance property on the invoked object
3. Attempting to access a `radius` property on `MyCircle` function's `prototype` which doesn't exist so evaluates to `undefined`
4. Creating an `area` instance property on the global window object and assigning it a function expression
5. Creating a `MyCircle` instance property on a `window` object and assigning to it the `MyCircle` function

**Summary:** It seems like it's creating an `area` and `MyCircle` properties on the global `window` object, and when `MyCircle` is invoked it creates an additional `radius` property.

**Usage:** MyCircle should be invoked before area since area relies on MyCircle initialising the radius:

```
window.MyCircle(10);
window.area(); // evaluates to 314
```